# on the density of hypersurfaces in complex projective spaces

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ag.algebraic-geometry

Good morning,

Let $H$ be a hypersurface in a complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^N.$ Let $d$ be the distance de Fubini-Study on $\mathbb{CP}^N.$

1. Let $x = [x_0: \ldots :x_N]$ and $y=[y_0:\ldots:y_N]$ two points in $\mathbb{CP}^N.$ Is the following formula true $$d(x,y)^2 = \frac{\sum_{i<j} |x_i \bar{y_j}-x_j\bar{y_i}|^2}{\sum |x_i|^2 \cdot \sum |y_i|^2}?$$
2. (principal question) Is the following quantity $$\max_{z\in \mathbb{CP}^N} d(z,H)$$ bounded from above by a quantity which depends only on the degree of $H?$ The expected quantity (which depends on the degree of $H$) must converge to $0$ as the degree of $H$ increases to $\infty.$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advances.

Duc Anh

Comment: This quantity is of course bounded from above by the diameter
of $CP^n$.

Comment: Indeed, that was my first thought. I think by "the expected quantity must go to zero" the OP wanted an upper bound decreasing in the degree (which there cannot be unless you impose further conditions like epsilon-transversality).

Comment: Where does the explicit formula for squared distance come from?

Comment: I think it comes from the usual formula in projective geometry. I'm sorry for the ambiguous reply but I asked this question for a long time.

Comment: Thank you for answering, dear Duc [sorry I can't write your name correctly :-)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning part 2), you could take a hyperplane with multiplicity k and then find a nearby hypersurface, so you could make the quantity you want arbitrarily close to the distance from a point to a hyperplane (hence independent of the degree). If you're interested in hypersurfaces which fill out projective space, Donaldson has a construction of sections of high degree line bundles which vanish "\epsilon-transversely" (i.e. pass steeply through the zero-section), and he proves that these converge as currents to the Kaehler form (in particular fill out the ambient space). See his famous 1996 JDG paper ["Symplectic submanifolds and almost complex geometry](http://www.intlpress.com/JDG/archive/1996/44-4-666.pdf)" (the relevant part for integrable complex structures is Section 6).

Comment: thank you very much. I have seen how naive my question is. Thank you also for recommanding the paper.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's naive, it seems like a reasonable idea that high degree hypersurfaces get complicated and fill up space. But as with all good reasonable ideas, it takes some effort to make sense of it.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that since I've received a downvote. But I will continue to ask some more questions.

Comment: The world is full of people who will think things are naive, but don't let that put you off: you ask questions for your sake, not for their sake. And often they're wrong anyway.